# Debugging third party app calls to a PHP script with PhpStorm

Tags: php, vb6, phpstorm, xdebug

**Context:**
I have configured PhpStorm with xDebug to debug my php scripts from the browser, this is working fine. I make calls to my php scripts through a web browser and PhpStorm is getting those calls.

**Problem:**
Now I need PhpStorm to receive the calls from another application that is not a web browser. I have a third app made in VB6 that is sending request to the scripts via Inet, but PhpStorm doesn't receive those calls. 
I don't know how to configure PhpStorm to "See" these requests so I can debug them.

Comment: Configure Xdebug for remote debugging and provide the port and handler (defaults to `xdbg:9000`) to the debugging part of the settings in PHPStorm. restart the service (if using a fcgi module like php-fpm, or apache if using php as a module for apache or IIS if it is SAPI)

Comment: You have to either pass additional xdebug parameter in your URL (so that xdebug knows that you wish to debug it (e.g. `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name` from https://xdebug.org/docs/remote) or configure xdebug to automatically attempt to debug every single request (`xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in your php.ini). In PhpStorm you will have to use "phone handle" icon so it listens for incoming debug connections. In any case: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" Worked fine!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line to the Php.ini solved my problem:

```
[XDebug]
...
...
...
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```